# Posição absoluta não funciona num menu fixo

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou com um seguinte problema, tenho uma div no body com posição absoluta, e tenho um menu em que o mesmo é fixo, tem-se sub-menus e para abri-los deve-se passar o mouse encima do menu,porém quando o mesmo é aberto ele fica atrás da div no body.

Fiddle para entender melhor:

http://jsfiddle.net/L6575yr0/5/

Obs: eu sei que removendo o fixed do menu resolve, mas não é possível fazer o mesmo por que deseja-se ter o menu na lateral quando ter mais conteúdo..

Comment: Não sei se eu entendi direito mas veja se removendo o **z-index** da classe **separator** é o que procura.

Answer (score 1):

Adicione o `z-index:999;` à classe `menu` também.

```
.menu
{
    ...
    z-index:999;
}
```

**Edit**: para documentar para a posteridade:

O `z-index` equivale à posição na coordenada Z; o eixo Z é tido como aquele que "sai" da tela e cresce em direção ao rosto do usuário. Ou seja: quanto maior o índice Z, **mais para "perto" do usuário o elemento vai**, sobrepondo-se àqueles com coordenada Z mais baixa.

O valor de 999 foi uma sugestão, tendo em vista que você já utiliza `z-index: 1` e `z-index: 999` e isto parece funcionar bem (não houve reclamação em relação à disposição inicial dos componentes, apenas em relação aos ítens do menu).

Porém, conforme o @FelipeStoker apontou, você pode fazer um estudo das coordenadas de acordo a organizar a sequência em que os ítens se sobrepõem no eixo Z. Caso, para 2 elementos A e B, não haja competição por espaço no plano XY (A nunca irá se sobrepor a B), um mesmo valor de `z-index` pode ser aplicado aos dois, sem prejuízo.

Comment: Junte explicação pff...

Answer (score 0):

Não é necessário você usar `z-index:999` em tudo. Você precisa analisar a estrutura e aplicar o `z-index` de forma crescente:

Por exemplo:

Você pode colocar no `.menu` um `z-index:2`, pois o `separator` tem `z-index:1`, e são divs distintas.

Ou seja, o correto é colocar:

```
.menu
{
    position: fixed;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    width: 47px;
    float:left;
    background:#ccc;
    z-index: 2;

}
```